# How can i check bearer token in swagger/nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, swagger, swagger-ui

I using swagger and I add auth today. But even if I write any letter like " a " or "abc" or what its still entering. How can I check is it true token for use swagger? My code:

```
const options = {
  definition: {
    openapi: "3.0.0",
    info: {
      title: "İlaç Takip Sistemi API",
      version: "2.0.0",
      description: "ITS API Swagger",
    },
    servers: [
      {
        url: "http://localhost:3100",
      },
    ],
    components: {
      securitySchemes: {
        bearerAuth: {
          type: "apiKey",
          name: "x-auth-token",
          scheme: "bearer",
          in: "header",
        },
      },
    },
    security: [
      {
        bearerAuth: [],
      },
    ],
  },
  apis: ["./app/routes.js"],
};
const specs = swaggerJsDoc(options);
app.use("/swagger", swaggerUI.serve, swaggerUI.setup(specs));
```

This is how i check Token :

```
jwt.verify(req.token, process.env.SECRETKEY, (err, authData) => {
      if (err) {
        res.sendStatus(401);
      } else {
        res.json(authData);
      }
    });
```

Comment: can you explain a little more, what do u mean "write any letter like " a " or "abc" or what its still entering". It's pretty hard to understand what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: @AritraChakraborty sure, i can explain, sorry for my bad english. I add authorization to swagger. When i open my swagger page i can see authorization symbol. When i click it its asking for a token like a password. I want to add some control function. For example when someone enter my swagger api, I dont want they use it without i gave token. But now even if you enter some random letters its still unlock for use my apis. Its not even check that parameters is a token or not. Even if u write A and click unlock its still unlock without control. I meant it.

Comment: You need to verify the token on the backend, not in Swagger UI. Swagger UI's "Authorize" dialog doesn't check the entered token by design, so that you can test requests containing both valid and invalid tokens (the former would get a valid response, the latter would get a 401 response - assuming you have proper auth checks on the backend).

Comment: @Helen thanks for reply! But i already checking it. I edit my question you can see how i checking it. When i write my token to swagger then do my works in there but when i try from swagger its saying Unauthorized even my token is true and working while i trying in postman.

Comment: Does your token need the `Bearer` prefix? If so, change your security scheme to `type: http` and remove `in` and `name`. (So that it's just `type: http` + `scheme: bearer`.) Does this resolve the issue?

Comment: @Helen Yes its solved! Thank you so much! U r a life-saver ahaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When i write my token to swagger then do my works in there but when i try from swagger its saying Unauthorized even my token is true and working while i trying in postman.

Change your security scheme as follows:

```js
        bearerAuth: {
          type: "http",
          scheme: "bearer",
        },
```

This way the "Bearer" prefix will be added automatically to the tokens you enter in Swagger UI.

When using `type: "apiKey"` for Bearer authentication, you would have to include the "Bearer " prefix in the token value, that is, enter the token as `Bearer abc123` in Swagger UI.